# What does pjsua_im_send do?

Tags: pjsip

I want to send IM by pjsua, I thought I can send any data by `pjsua_im_send`, which there has a parameter named `void *user_data`. BUT the parameter's description said it will be given back when the IM callback is called. Then I read the source code of `pjsua_im.c`, IM callback just for outgoing MSG. SO, if the remote peer can't recive this parameter, what does it for? AND can I send other MIME_TYPE except `plain/text`? HOW?

Answer (score 0):

You can send any custom data to your remote peer if you serialize it in JSON, XML etc. If the serialization is a not a way to go (due performance limitations, remote peers limitation etc.) you can try to send binary data "as is" wrapping it into **pj_str_t** because it has both "data pointer" and "length of the data" fields that could play safe for zero-containing arrays.